# Como usar o isEnabled do spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Eu queria saber se estou usando o método isEnabled do spring security corretamente. Pois no meu sistema, todo usuário tem uma lista de perfis. Se o admin remover todos os seus perfis e o usuário tentar logar com aquela conta sem perfil deve ser disparada uma exceção para ele informando que a conta está inativa.

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException{

    Usuario usuario =  usuarioRepository.findByEmail(email);

    if(usuario == null)
    {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);
    }

    if(usuario.getPerfis().isEmpty())
    {
        usuarioLogado.isEnabled();
        //throw new AuthorizationException("Usuário bloqueado!");
    }

    return new UserSpringSecurity(usuario.getId(), usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getSenha(), usuario.getNome(), usuario.getPerfis());
}
```

Implementação do isEnabled na classe que implementa o UserDetails

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

Esse código acima funciona como eu esperava quando o usuário tenta fazer login, disparando a exceção de status 401. O problema está no método do refresh token, que dispara a mensagem de exceção correta, mas com status de erro 500.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/refresh_token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> refreshToken(HttpServletResponse response){
    UserSpringSecurity usuarioLogado = UserService.authenticated();
    //jwtUtil.checkIfPerfilIsEmpty(usuarioLogado);
    String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(usuarioLogado.getUsername());
    response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    response.addHeader("access-control-expose-headers", "Authorization");
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

Tentei usar esse codigo acima pra verificar se o usuario logado tem algum perfil e disparar a exceção com o método checkIfPerfilIsEmpty, mas o resultado foi o mesmo, então comentei a linha.

Pesquisei la na doc do spring, mas so diz pra que o método serve. [doc do spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html)
Como eu não achei em lugar nenhum uma explicação, não sei se usei corretamente.